# Ideal way to transition text when fading in/fading out

Tags: javascript

Throughout my code I constantly fade the text out, update it, then fade it back in for a smooth transition. I've noticed though that a lot of times the text will update a split second before it fully fades out. I'm not sure if maybe I'm using a bad approach.

This is how I'm doing it right now. Is there a better way?

```
function showInfo(text = '') {
    freeze_input = true
    fadeOut(question_text, '.125s')
    setTimeout(() => {
        question_text.style.display = ''
        if (text !== '') {
            question_text.innerText = text
        }
        fadeIn(question_text, '.125s')
        freeze_input = false
    }, 125)
}

function fadeIn(element, time = '.25s') {
    console.log('fading in ', element, ' for ', time)
    element.style.transition = time
    element.style.opacity = '1'
    element.style.visibility = 'visible'
}

function fadeOut(element, time = '.25s') {
    console.log('fading out ', element, ' for ', time)
    element.style.transition = time
    element.style.opacity = '0'
    element.style.visibility = 'hidden'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove those two line:

```
element.style.visibility = 'visible'
element.style.visibility = 'hidden'
```

The visibility behavior work the same like display in css. For smooth transition it's bad idea use visibility.

If you need smooth transition and then remove element from the DOM, use 2 times setTimeout.
First for transition to hide element, second for remove element from DOM.